# Postfix: How to write postfix rule of from and to

Tags: api, email, server, postfix-mta

How to write a postfix rule to allow the specific sender to send email to only one specific recipient only.

For example, sender@gmail.com can send emails to recipient@gmail.com only.

I have tried the below rule to set in header_checks,

```
/^From:.*sender@gmail.com.*To:.*recipient@gmail.com/ OK
/^From:.*sender@gmail.com/ REJECT Only allowed to send email to recipient@gmail.com
```

but it's not working properly. It returns error like "REJECT Only allowed to send email to recipient@gmail.com" for recipient@gmail.com also, while it should allow recipient@gmail.com to send

Comment: This sounds like a Postfix question, not a PHP question. If you have issues with some specific PHP code, then please add that to the question (and the code). If it's about Postfix rules, please remove the PHP tag.

Comment: `^From:.*sender@gmail.com.*To:.*recipient@gmail.com` looks for a `From:` header with a `To:` header embedded somewhere after it on the same line; surely not what you want.